# What are the penalties patent attorneys can be held accountable for false claims in a patent

Tags: invalid

I had another patent attorney view my issued patent and said my patent was invalid. I first filed my non provisional 2008 then my attorney filed a continuation in part because he did not add a very important claim, which he knew about beforehand, in 2009, he then abandoned the claim and re-filed in 2012. I finally got my patent two years after that. I had been selling my product since 2009 and my patent attorneys knew that. Now, that I have a license deal, I had another patent attorney view the contract where he said my patent is worthless and it is fraud. Without going to court, how can I get my patent attorney who filed the claims to correct this issue?